# Heroku - rpush_daemon crashes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, google-cloud-messaging

I am using Rpush gem(https://github.com/rpush/rpush) to push GCM notifications for one of my RoR projects. I am hosting it on Heroku. When I start my rpush_daemon, it's starts and with in no time, it shows as crashed. When I check my logs, it's says nothing clear about the issue
Please find the log out below

```
heroku[rpush_daemon.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
heroku[rpush_daemon.1]: Starting process with command `bundle exec rpush start --rails-env=production`
heroku[rpush_daemon.1]: State changed from starting to up
app[rpush_daemon.1]: * Booting Rails 'production' environment... ✔
heroku[rpush_daemon.1]: Process exited with status 0
heroku[rpush_daemon.1]: State changed from up to crashed
```

Below are the commands I tried,

```
heroku ps:restart rpush_daemon -a myApp
heroku scale rpush_daemon=1 -a myApp
heroku ps:restart -a myApp
```

Nothing works.

FYI: I have created applications for both Rpuush::GCM and Rpush::Apns.
Same is working fine in my local machine

Please help me out to figure what's wrong.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Since rpush will run as a daemon procoess(when started using rpush start) heroku crashes the process. According to Heroku docs, any process running as a daemon/background process will be crashed my heroku itself. Hence, starting rpush in foreground must fix the problem.
You can start rpush in foreground using following command

```
bundle exec rpush start -f
```